# How can I redirect valgrind output (Heap summary) alongside my program's output in a command?

Tags: bash, shell, valgrind

Hello I'm trying to run valgrind on several input files to find out if there are any memory leaks in my program and want to get the program output alongside valgrind's heap summary into seperate files, I'd appreciate some help

I tried running the following lines:

```
for i in {0..99}

do

  valgrind --leak-check=full --leak-resolution=med --track-origins=yes --vgdb=no

  ./IndustrialTakeover<./tests/input/in${i}.txt>./tests/valgrind_check/program/output${i}.txt

done
```

but this doesn't provide the heap summary output into a file of their own

and then I tried running :

```
for i in {0..99}

do
  valgrind --log-file=./tests/valgrind_check/valgrind_message/output${i}.txt

  --leak-check=full --leak-resolution=med --track-origins=yes --vgdb=no

  ./IndustrialTakeover<./tests/input/in${i}.txt>./tests/valgrind_check/program/output${i}.txt

done
```

but it also didn't work and I got the message

> valgrind: Use --help for more information.
>
> --leak-check=full: command not found
>
> valgrind: no program specified

, would appreciate some help!

Comment: Please take a look at [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formattin

Comment: make your command with valgrind in a single line, if on multiple lines you need to add a "/" line break like https://google.github.io/styleguide/shellguide.html#pipelines # All fits on one line
command1 | command2

# Long commands
command1 \
  | command2 \
  | command3 \
  | command4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution to this problem is using the following lines:

```
for i in {0..99} ;
do
  valgrind valgrind --log-file=./tests/valgrind_check/valgrindmessage/output${i}.txt --leak-check=full --leak-resolution=med --track-origins=no --vgdb=no./IndustrialTakeover<./tests/input/in${i}.txt>./tests/valgrind_check/program/output${i}.txt ;
done
```

but ofcourse you'll have to replace the range in the for loop, app with your own app and paths with your own paths.

Answer (score 1):

A more Valgrind-y way of doing this is to incorporate the pid into the log file name, like this:

```
for i in {0..99} ;
do
  valgrind valgrind --log-file=./tests/valgrind_check/valgrindmessage/valgrind.%p.log --leak-check=full --leak-resolution=med --track-origins=no --vgdb=no ./IndustrialTakeover < ./tests/input/in${i}.txt > ./tests/valgrind_check/program/output${i}.txt ;
done
```

Valgrind will replace the %p with the pid.

This is particularly useful if you are using `--trace-children=yes` as it will also generate one log per process spawned.

Comment: hey @Paul Floyd , thanks for the answer. I tried running the line you provided but it didn't work, I don't really understand the change you added can you please explain it to me or link me to a website that gives a good explanation of it

Comment: I only copied the Valgrind line - you still need the for loop for ${i} in the output log. I've edited the answer.